# Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'

Tags: c#, json, rest, firebase, xamarin

I am currently creating a mobile app using Xamarin and testing out with the RESTful API service.

I am currently following this sample [tutorial](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoREST/TodoREST) provided by Xamarin.

However, when I tried to save my inputs into my Firebase database, I get the error mentioned at the title. May I know what's the error? I have tried googling but there's no answer to it.

The code snippet is

```
public async Task SaveTodoItemAsync(TodoItem item, bool isNewItem = false){
....
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
....
}
```